# How do I implement a pre-commit hook script in SVN that calls dos2unix to validate checked-in file

Tags: python, svn, dos2unix

I was wondering if anyone here had some experience writing this type of script and if they could give me some pointers.

I would like to modify this [script](http://wordaligned.org/articles/a-subversion-pre-commit-hook) to validate that the check-in file does not have a Carriage Return in the EOL formatting. The EOL format is CR LF in Windows and LF in Unix. When a User checks-in code with the Windows format. It does not compile in Unix anymore. I know this can be done on the client side but I need to have this validation done on the server side. To achieve this, I need to do the following:

1) Make sure the file I check is not a binary, I dont know how to do this with svnlook, should I check the mime:type of the file? The [Red Book](http://svnbook.red-bean.com/nightly/en/svn.reposadmin.create.html) does not indicate this clearly or I must have not seen it.

2) I would like to run the [dos2unix](http://linux.about.com/od/commands/l/blcmdl1_dos2uni.htm) command to validate that the file has the correct EOL format. I would compare the output of the dos2unix command against the original file. If there is a diff between both, I give an error message to the client and cancel the check-in.

I would like your comments/feedback on this approach.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think you can avoid a commit hook script in this case by using the `svn:eol-style` property as described in the SVNBook:

- [End-of-Line Character Sequences](http://svnbook.red-bean.com/en/1.7/svn.advanced.props.file-portability.html#svn.advanced.props.special.eol-style)
- [Subversion Properties](http://svnbook.red-bean.com/en/1.7/svn.ref.properties.html)

This way SVN can worry about your line endings for you.

Good luck!

Comment: Thanks Stephen, I implemented the svn:eol-style property on all my source files instead of using pre-commit hooks

Comment: What did you set it to? `native` or `LF` ?  What is the default setting if svn:eol-style hasn't been set?

Answer (score 1):

What exactly are you trying to do?

Of course, there are numerous places to learn about svn pre-commit hooks (e.g.  [here](http://wordaligned.org/articles/a-subversion-pre-commit-hook) ,  [here](http://www.windley.com/archives/2008/08/using_a_precommit_hook_to_check_puppet_syntax.shtml), and in the [Red Book](http://svnbook.red-bean.com/nightly/en/svn.reposadmin.create.html)) but it depends what you're trying to do and what is available on your system.

Can you be more specific?